# NetSuite Suitelet Sublist Paging Handling Method and Top Page Index List Position Adjustment

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Hello NetSweet developers.
I am a beginner developer who has just been responsible for NetSuite development at our company. I have one question.
I developed a search page using Suitelet. Therefore, we succeeded in injecting the result into the sublist using the N/search module. However, there is one regret.
I created the page index as a single field, and the location exists in a location that is in a format contrary to the experience of many users. Is there any way to modify the location of this field to match the form on the Script Deployment page?

Pages I developed:

[image]

I want to be modified like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem!

It was just a matter of changing the type of LIST to'STATICLIST'.

Although the number is limited to 25 records, we were able to implement a UI/UX closer to the NetSuite UI.